# Laravel 5.2 not working on php 7 on Windows 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have followed every direction but I cannot get Laravel 5.2 to work on php 7 on Windows 10. On the same server I have Laravel 4.2 (this is the app I want to upgrade) working with no issues whatsoever. None of the answers on similar questions seem to work.

The error I get is:

```
No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.
```

If I chage the cipher method to MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 the error becomes:

```
mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 0 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported
```

I have tried

- php artisan key:generate
- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan clear-compiled
- php artisan config:clear
- adding app key to /config/app.php, deleting the .env file, adding the key to both .env and app.php and still does not work.

Currently, my .env file looks like this.

[image: .env file]

and my app.php file looks like this.
[image: app.php]

How do I solve this problem? Currently only the home page is working. The login and register pages fail with the errors specified above.

Laravel was installed like this: `create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel appdir`

Comment: You app.php `key` is set to find an env key of `somestring` and not the app key. So `'key' => env('APP_KEY')`

Comment: @NIcklas Thank you. This worked. I really feel stupid now, like I wasted everyone's time. This is the answer. Not sure how to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry this is a common problem that is easy to miss.

In your `app.php` file you are trying to find an env key of `somestring` (in this case the actual value you want to return) and not the **key** in which you set the **value** in the env file.

Setting the `key` in your `app.php` file as the following:

`'key' => env('APP_KEY')`

Should correctly look for the `APP_KEY` in your env file and set the corresponding value!